# Wish to display top `2 blogs items` with largest views, but it is displaying all of the blogs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Wish to display top `2 blogs items` with largest views. I have tried below code, but it is displaying all of the blogs now, any thoughts on what could be the issue here ?

```
 const [popularResults, setPopularResults] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            const res = await axios.get(`${appUrl}/service/listofblogs`);
            setPopularResults(res.data.blogData);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        }
        fetchData();
      }, []);
    
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setPopularResults(popularResults.sort((a, b) => b.views - a.views).slice(0, 2))
      }, []);

    const MostPopularBlogs = () =>
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='trendingArea'>
        { popularResults.map (({id, blogdetails, views, createdAt }) => (
          <a> 
            <div key={id} 
             onClick={
              () =>
                navigate("popularBlogDetails", {
                  state: { id, blogdetails, views, createdAt}
                })
              } 
             className='popularArea'>
              <ReactMarkdown  children={blogdetails} className='dataDate renderElipsis tags readmoreLink views' remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]}> 
              </ReactMarkdown>
              <div className='blogDate'>
                {moment(createdAt).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')}
                 <a className='readmoreLink'>
                  Read more →
                 </a>
                 <div className='blogViews'>
                {views > 999 ? (views / 1000).toFixed(2) + "K" : views}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
            ))} 
        </div>
     </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that your second `useEffect` is finishing before the first one since the first one involves async operations. And so, although you are setting the `popularResults` variable to the top 2 based on views in the second `useEffect`, the first one is overriding that and setting this variable to every single blog returned from the backend call.

You can fix this by ditching the second `useEffect` and then create a variable that essentially does the same thing that the second useEffect was doing (i.e. grabbing the top two blogs based on views)

```
 const [popularResults, setPopularResults] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            const res = await axios.get(`${appUrl}/service/listofblogs`);
            setPopularResults(res.data.blogData);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        }
        fetchData();
      }, []);

const topTwo = popularResults.sort((a, b) => b.views - a.views).slice(0, 2)
```

Then run the `.map` on `topTwo` instead of `popularResults`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason for using two `useEffect` hooks here. 
Even if the first `useEffect` ends first, `popularResults` is still equal to `[]` when the second one begins.
 The state will only be updated when the component re-renders so you cannot return a sorted array based on it.
 what you have to do is to get advantage of the API returned data and sort it  then update your state once and for all so use only one `useEffect` to mange all the work, you fetch then you sort then you update:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`${appUrl}/service/listofblogs`);
      const final = res.data.blogData.sort((a, b) => b.views - a.views).slice(0, 2);
      setPopularResults(final);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);
```